# Adaptive .mp4 Video Streaming Using ExoPlayer

Tags: android, video-streaming, mp4, exoplayer

I am working on a video streaming application, where I have to stream `.mp4` videos. I am using `exoplayer` to play the videos. The problem is in low bandwidth connections the videos are buffering. so I wanted to implement `adaptive streaming`. I have checked the documentation and implemented similar to [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro/#4).
But the streaming did not work. So I have checked documentation of `HLS` streaming and `Dashed` streaming. but `HLS` streaming requires `m3u8` file and `Dash` streaming requires `.mpd` format however mine is `.mp4`. is there any workaround or methods so that I can implement adaptive streaming ?

Comment: Have you find any solution to the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No workarounds. Adaptive streaming requires adaptive formats.

Comment: is there any way to convert .mp4 to any of those adaptive formats in client ?

Comment: If I have fragmented mp4 is it possible to implement Adaptive Bitrate streaming in the client side

Answer (score -1):

You can use adaptive streaming with MP4 with a player that can switch between videos based upon the bitrate of the connection. So you would have 3-6 different MP4 based upon your customer needs (4K, 2K, 1080p, 720p, 640p, 480p, 360p, ...)
The JWplayer can do that, so can others. Encoding is a CPU heavy process, so you cannot do it on the client, it should be done on the server-side before or during broadcasting.

Comment: hope you have read the question. I know what is adaptive streaming. I have asked an alternative solution for that. and do you think keeping 3-6 copies videos for single video is the best solution ?